# Limits on overflowed integrals are too far away from the integral sign

Tags: bug, mathjax

I edited [Multiplying divergent integrals using Hardy fields approach](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/421354/multiplying-divergent-integrals-using-hardy-fields-approach) to put equations clearly meant to be displayed in display mode.  Once I did so, one of the equations exhibited very strange spacing, which I cannot account for from the source:
[image: Multi-line integral with strange spacing on second line]

```
$$\int_0^\infty e^x dx\cdot\int_0^\infty e^x dx=\int_0^\infty (2 e^{2 x}-2 e^x)dx=2\int_0^\infty e^{2 x}dx-2\int_0^\infty e^x dx.$$
```

As you can see, all integrals are coded the same way, and the integrals on the first line appear as expected, but the limits on the second integral are too far away from the $\int$ sign.  (It is explicitly something about multi-line display, because increasing my window size and refreshing shows the limits in the last integral spaced as the others as soon as they are all on the same line.)

Thanks to @MartinSleziak for [reminding me](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5318/limits-on-overflowed-integrals-are-too-far-away-from-the-integral-sign#comment27234_5318) to include the renderer I am using.  It is HTML-CSS with Fast Preview.  Here is the equation as MathJax, not an image:
$$\int_0^\infty e^x dx\cdot\int_0^\infty e^x dx=\int_0^\infty (2 e^{2 x}-2 e^x)dx=2\int_0^\infty e^{2 x}dx-2\int_0^\infty e^x dx.$$

Comment: It might be good to include the information about the MathJax Renderer you're using. (See here: [How do I change Math Renderer for MathJax?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30859)) And possibly you might include the rendered version of the formula, too. (So that other people can test how the same expression behaves for them - especially in case the linked post gets deleted.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak, [thanks](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5318/limits-on-overflowed-integrals-are-too-far-away-from-the-integral-sign#comment27234_5318)!  I have done so for the renderer.  When you say to include the rendered version, I guess you mean to include the MathJax source, so that the equation renders here, rather than just an image of the rendering that I see?  I have now done that, too.

Comment: This was [fixed in MathJax version 2.7.8](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/2139), but unfortunately, StackExchange has not upgraded from v2.7.5 (the current version for version 2 is 2.7.9).  The fix is for SE to upgrade to 2.7.8 or 2.7.9.

Comment: This is more a LaTEX suggestion, but when dealing with these spacing problem I use extensively the directive `\limits`: it looks often better $$\int\limits_0^\infty e^x dx\cdot\int\limits_0^\infty e^x dx=\int\limits_0^\infty (2 e^{2 x}-2 e^x)dx=2\int\limits_0^\infty e^{2 x}dx-2\int\limits_0^\infty e^x dx.$$

Comment: @DanieleTampieri, thanks for the [suggestion](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5318/limits-on-overflowed-integrals-are-too-far-away-from-the-integral-sign#comment27285_5318)!  To me those integrals are far too tall, and I particularly don't like the effect when integrating over a set, like $\displaystyle\int\limits_{\mathbb R} e^x\mathrm dx$; but of course to each their own!  But anyway imposing it on everyone, whatever your and my tastes, probably isn't the solution, so hopefully we'll upgrade to the new MathJax soon.

Comment: You're right, mine is only a suggestion based on my personal tastes: however, I also agree with you that, when dealing about an integral over a set $A$, $$\int_A f(x)\operatorname{d\!} x\;\text{ looks far better than }\;\int\limits_A f(x)\operatorname{d\!} x$$.